# Multiple panel plot non-NA error

Tags: r, panel, lattice, lm

I've got a data frame that looks like this.

```
a[,2:25]
     UT1 UT2 UT3 UT4 UT5 UT6 UT7 UT8 UT9 UT10 UT11 UT12 TR1 TR2 TR3 TR4
3094   9   0   1  37   6   2   8   1   1    6    3    1   3   0   0   1
3095   4   0   0  10  17   6   7   1   5    3    1   12   2   0   0   1
3096  18   0   0   4   6  15  14   0   7    9    3    8   5   2   1   2
3097  11   0   0   7   5  15  10   2   4    7   16   17   7   3   0   0
3098  18   0  11   2   5  11   7   3   2    1    1    0   3   3   1   1
3099  25   0   6  11  17   3  10   1   1    3    9    2   2   1   1   2
3100   1   0   1  27  12  28  27   0   2   11    6    0   1   7   4   6
3101   0   0   1  40   0  17  13   1   0    3    3    0   1   3   3   1
3102   2   0   0  30   1   9   2   1   1    5    0    0   1   3   3   0
3103   3   0   0  11   4   7   5   2   4    0    1    0   5   4   0   0
3104   5   0   0   3   1  10   4   2   3    0    3    0   7   2   1   0
     TR5 TR6 TR7 TR8 TR9 TR10 TR11 TR12
3094   1   0  15   3   0    0   42    1
3095   1   0   4  29   0    0   42    0
3096   0   0   3  22   0    0    3    0
3097   1   0   4  14   0    0    2    0
3098   0   0   1  10   0    0    1    0
3099   0   0   4  41   1    0    3    0
3100   0   0  10  21   0    0   17    0
3101   0   0   2   1   1    0   13    3
3102   0   0   2   4   0    0   10    3
3103   1   0   3   4   0    0   12    1
3104   0   0   1   2   0    0    8    0
```

The first column of my data it's time so I separated it using

```
tiempo<-a$Tiempo
tiempo
 [1] 618.6 618.8 619.0 619.2 619.4 619.6 619.8 620.0 620.2 620.4 620.6
```

In order to plot each column as a fucntion of time and do lm I used reshape `package` and `lattice`. I'm not sure that's the best option but almost gets me what I want.
The code looks like this:

```
m<-melt(a[,2:25])
f<-m$variable
xyplot(m$value~tiempo | f, panel=function(x,y,...){
  panel.xyplot(x,y,...)
  panel.lmline(x,y, col=2, lty=2)
})
```

And the output is this graph

[image]

I don't get why it gives this error, I expect them to be non-NA, I don't understand why it is a problem. In fact, the first panel worked just fine.

When I change the panel.lmline(...) part this happens:

```
xyplot(m$value~tiempo | f, panel=function(x,y,...){
  panel.xyplot(tiempo,m$value,...)
  panel.lmline(tiempo,m$value, col=2, lty=2)
})
```

[image]

I get this lenght error but I think it's because each panel is using all datapoints from m when it should be using only 11.

The lm regression function I use is separated from the plotting and this doesn't mess with my statistical analysis but I'm trying to put everything together and won't be able to do it if I can't plot the data. I want visual information about the regression in order to be able to remove outliers if the Rsquared is too low or maybe not even consider that observation.

I hope I've made myself clear.
Thank you very much

Edited with suggestions

[image]

Comment: If you just do `xyplot(m$value~tiempo | f)` do you get the expected plot, minus the lmline?

Comment: You need to reshape with the time variable. Lengths need to match up. 
Do this `a.melt <-melt(a, id.var="tiempo")`

Comment: @infominer when I use xyplot(a.melt$value~a.melt$Tiempo | f) I get all the different panles but I get "extra values" plotted. I don't know what extra information is plotting. I edited the question for you to see it

Comment: @JohnPaul I don't get the correct plot doing that. It looks like the first one but without the lm

Comment: @MatiasAndina just do `xyplot(value ~ Tiempo | variable, data  = a.melt, ....)` Replace the ... with the panel functions you defined in your Question.

Comment: @infominer that worked fine! why don't you answer so I can give you some credit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got most of the code right.

It would be better to use the time (tiempo) variable as an id variable in your `melt` call
This will ensure the lengths of the data match up.

```
library(reshape2) #This is faster version of reshape
df.m <- melt(df.matias, id.var="Tiempo") #I stored your data in df.matias
```

Now we can use the melted data to make your plot

```
library(lattice)
xyplot(value ~ Tiempo | variable, data = df.m,
   panel = function(x,y,...) {
     panel.xyplot(x,y,...)
     panel.lmline(x,y, col = 2, lty =2)
})
```